# What uses the Grasp Message?

Tags: ros, object-manipulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to use the PR2_grasp_adjust package and associated service call [GraspAdjust](http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/pr2_grasp_adjust/html/srv/GraspAdjust.html). However, I can't figure out what to do with the `Grasp` message once the service returns. Is there a particular service that takes Grasp messages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31071/what-uses-the-grasp-message?/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2012-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A Grasp can be passed on to the PickupAction, serviced by the object_manipulator. You can see an example of calling that action here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Simple%20Pick%20and%20Place%20Application

Note that, unlike the example, you will be populating the desired_grasps field of the PickupGoal with your computed grasp.

Another example can be found in the pr2_interactive_manipulation package, in the file that Adam mentioned above.

---

Originally posted by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) with karma: 586 on 2012-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are successfully getting grasps back from Grasp Adjust, then you'll need to pass those to a grasp executor. I'm a little fuzzy on how the grasp pipeline works downstream from the planners; object_manipulator has a node that will execute object pickup actions. A usage example is the pickup_client in pr2_interactive_manipulation/src/interactive_manipulation_backend.cpp

If you are working in Python, though, I think Kaijen might have some other handy interfaces for executing grasps. I don't really remember where those are though.

---

Originally posted by [aleeper](https://answers.ros.org/users/35/aleeper/) with karma: 573 on 2012-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1